# Find mismatches values in the same row of a table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table named laptops with multiple rows. The 3 fields that I have plus 4 sample rows are:

```
item_id  |  operating_system   |   item_title
-------+-------------+-------------
1     | Windows 10 | Toshiba with Windows 10 Pro and a mouse
2     | Windows 10 Pro | HP with Windows 10 Pro
3     | Linux | Dell with Windows 10
4     | iOS 11 | Random Apple laptop
```

What I need is to solve the following use cases:

1. **Get mismatches:** Pull only the rows where the operating system showing up as part of the item_title IS NOT the one listed in operating_system. item_title would contain as a string any other operating system in the operating_system column. This is the case of IDs #1 and #3
2. **String values within other values:** Some operating_system string values are included in other larger values. For instance, someone can say that id #1 is correct because 'Windows 10' shows up in the item_title, BUT IT ISN'T because the actual value there is 'Windows 10 Pro', so that's a mismatch as well.

Honestly I'm quite blocked on how to do this, I started a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM laptops
WHERE item_name NOT LIKE ('%'+operating_system+'%')
```

but my SQL knowledte is limited and I don't know how to achieve the 2 use cases I presented.

Comment: do you have a list (table) of known and valid operating systems?

Comment: The values in the operating_system column should all be valid and the source of truth in this case. The issue is the mismatch with the item title.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT
  item_name
FROM laptops
WHERE item_title NOT LIKE '%' || operating_system || '%'
```

For example, it would resolve to:

```
WHERE 'HP with Windows 10 Pro' NOT LIKE '%Windows 10 Pro%'
```